# Изменение картинки при наведении на родительский компонент в React.JS

Tags: reactjs, события, mouse-event

Всех приветствую, верстаю компонент услуг на сайте, где у каждой услуги есть своя иконка в двух вариантах - стандартная (серая) и при наведении (синяя):

[image: 1]

Дизайнер и заказчик хотят, чтобы при наведении на блок менялось изображение со Смеситель_off.png на Смеситель_on.png (названия условные). Сейчас, в компоненте услуги картинка подтягивается из "коллекции" картинок в другом компоненте:

```
// Здесь я импортирую картинки для компонента услуг
import Смеситель_off from '../Смеситель off.png';
import Смеситель_on from '../Смеситель on.png';


export {
  Смеситель_off,
  Смеситель_on,
}
```

Затем я передаю эти картинками пропсами через состояние. Так их можно будет динамически менять в случае чего:

```
// В этом файле определяется список услуг, на основе количества элементов в состоянии [services]
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ServicesItem from '../ServicesItem.jsx';

const ServicesListMiddle = () => {

    const [services] = useState ([
        {
            imgOff: 'Смеситель_off',
            imgOn: 'Смеситель_on',
        }
    ])

    return (

        <section className='services_middle'>
            {services.map(service => 

                <ServicesItem
                    imgOff={service.imgOff}
                    imgOn={service.imgOn}
                />

            )}
        </section>
    );
}

export default ServicesListMiddle;
```

И, соответственно, задаю исходную картинку компоненту по умолчанию:

```
// Это сама карточка услуги
import React from 'react';
import * as Img from '../Img.jsx'  // Коллекция картинок

const ServiceItem = (props) => {
    return (  
        <div onMouseEnter={???}>
            <img src={Img[`${props.imgOff}`]}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Всё бы ничего, но в Реакте довольно запутанная история с изменениями в DOM-дереве по событию. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при наведении `(onMouseEnter)` по родительскому диву, картинка меняла своё состояние на другую картинку из коллекции картинок, желательно плавно, как это делается через css с помощью `transition`.
Знающие люди, подскажите, пожалуйста, как быть. Желательно, чтобы это не сильно отличалось от подхода который сейчас у меня (через пропсы и коллекцию картинок). Но если есть более простой или правильный подход - так же учту, переделаю и буду благодарен.
Всем заранее спасибо!

Comment: Удобнее работать по системе "спрайтов" https://learn.javascript.ru/css-sprite Т.е. картинка всегда одна и в ней все варианты отображения. Т.о. в css ты просто указываешь смещение картинки в бекграунде.

Comment: Так же можно поместить обе картинки в один div, далее в css указать какой виден без наведения и какой с наведением...

Comment: Используй css и всё.

Comment: @Свойство background-image не рассматривается заказчиком

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае можно обойтись без js, а использовать только CSS

```css
.wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper img{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
}

.wrapper:hover img:last-child {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://emojio.ru/images/apple-b/1f31a.png"/>
  <img src="https://emojio.ru/images/apple-b/1f31d.png"/>
</div
```